# How to reduce partition processing time

Tags: ssis, parallel-processing, ssas

During creating partitions for cube, I forced a problem with time of partition processing. Whole cube without partitions processed 51 minutes.
I created monthly partitions for measure groups. I checked time of processing for one month partition for each measure group (it lasted up to 2.30 minutes). I processed them manually, chosing one partition (the same month for each measure group) and together it lasted around 15 minutes.

I assumed, that when I process the partition parallel, it will take much less time. However I created SSIS package, adding "*Analysis Services Processing Task*" and chosing all partitions. For this task I chose *processing order = Parallel*. I run The package and it took around 16 minutes (so even more than manual, sequential partition processing).

I tried also to process partitions parallel, using XMLA script:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
<Parallel>
<Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>OLAP_Partitioning_20130222</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>Usage</CubeID>
    <MeasureGroupID>Partition1</MeasureGroupID>
    <PartitionID>Partition1_20130101-20130131</PartitionID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
</Parallel>
<Parallel>
<Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>OLAP_Partitioning_20130222</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>Usage</CubeID>
    <MeasureGroupID>Partition2</MeasureGroupID>
    <PartitionID>Partition2_20130101-20130131</PartitionID>
  </Object>
  <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
```

It also took more than 15 minutes. Could anyone give me any tips, what I'm doing wrong? How can I optimize partition processing time?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother fussing with partitions when at best you might save 5-10 minutes, but anyway... Do you have SQL Server Enterprise? Other editions will not process in parallel.

Comment: Yes, we have SQL Server Enterprise.

Comment: In that case I would look at your query performance.  You may have gone from 1 table scan to 16 table scans ...